# Laravel 5.6: error con relación m:m metodo sync

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente método para editar el usuario:

```
public function editar_usuario(Request $request) {

        $roles = Role::get();
        $id= $request->only('id');
        $usuario = DB::table('usuario.users')->where('id',$id)->first();
        $perfil1=($usuario->id_perfil);
        if ($usuario) { 
            $perfil= DB::table('usuario.perfil')->get(); 
            $perfil2 = DB::table('usuario.perfil')->where('id',$perfil1)->first();
            return view("usuarios.editar",compact('usuario','perfil','perfil2', 'roles'));
        } 
}
```

El siguiente metodo es para el update:

```
public function editar_user(Request $request, User $user) {      //guarda usuario editado 

        //echo "edit_user";
        //dd("pass:".$request->password);

        if ($request->password != ''){
            $validatorname =Validator::make($request->only('name'),[
                'name'=>'required|min:3|max:50',
            ]);
            $validatorapellido=Validator::make($request->only('apellido'),[
                'apellido'=>'required|min:3|max:50',
            ]);
            $validatorpregunta=Validator::make($request->only('pregunta'),[
                'pregunta'=>'required|min:3|max:50',
            ]);
            $validatorrespuesta=Validator::make($request->only('respuesta'),[
                'respuesta'=>'required|min:3|max:50',
            ]);
            $validatorpassword=Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
                'password_confirmation' => 'min:6|same:password'
                ]);
            $data = $request->only('id','name','apellido','username','id_perfil','pregunta','respuesta','password');
        }           


        else{
            $validatorname =Validator::make($request->only('name'),[
                'name'=>'required|min:3|max:50',
            ]);
            $validatorapellido=Validator::make($request->only('apellido'),[
                'apellido'=>'required|min:3|max:50',
            ]);
            $validatorpregunta=Validator::make($request->only('pregunta'),[
                'pregunta'=>'required|min:3|max:50',
            ]);
            $validatorrespuesta=Validator::make($request->only('respuesta'),[
                'respuesta'=>'required|min:3|max:50',
            ]);

            $data = $request->only('id','name','apellido','username','id_perfil','pregunta','respuesta','password');
        }

        $id=$data['id'];

        if ($validatorname->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors(['Error nombre']);
        }
        if ($validatorapellido->fails()) {
                        return back()->withErrors(['Error apellido']);
                    }
        if ($validatorpregunta->fails()) {
                        return back()->withErrors(['Error pregunta']);
                    }
        if ($validatorrespuesta->fails()) {
                        return back()->withErrors(['Error respuesta']);
                    }
        if ($validatorpassword->fails()) {
                        return back()->withErrors(['Error password']);
                    }

        $update=DB::table('usuario.users')->where('id',$id)->update($data);

        //$user= User::update($data);

        $user->roles()->sync($request->get('roles'));

        if ($update) {          
            $usuarios= User::paginate(25);       
            return view('listados.listado_usuarios', $user->id)->with("usuarios", $usuarios);
        } 
    }
```

En el `edit` yo selecciono un rol para ese usuario que se esta editando, luego al darle aceptar y mandar los datos con el sync relaciono el user con roles. Con sync se manda id del usuario y el id del role seleccionado a una tabla pivote llamado `role_users`. Sucede que cuando envio los datos obtengo el siguiente error.

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  el valor null para la
>   columna «user_id» viola la restricción not null\n DETAIL:  La fila que
>   falla contiene (12, 1, null, 2018-07-13 17:31:59, 2018-07-13
>   17:31:59). (SQL: insert into "role_user" ("created_at", "role_id",
>   "updated_at", "user_id") values (2018-07-13 17:31:59, 1, 2018-07-13
>   17:31:59, ))

Es decir, en la tabla `role_user` crea el id de `role_user`, pasa el id del rol pero el id del usuario lo manda null.

**EDIT1:**

Las columnas de role_user son:

```
user_role

id, user_id, role_id
```

Role_user es una tabla pivote usada por un paquete de roles y permisos llamado shinobi que relaciona a user con role.

La relacion de user y role es de muchos a muchos.

**EDIT2:**

El problema principal es que el valor de las columnas de `role_user` que son: `id`, `role_id` y `user_id`, la única que no le esta llegando el valor en el edit es `user_id`.

Si yo creo el modelo `role_user` ¿Como haría para pasar este valor directamente a la tabla `role_user`? Ya que como no se esta pasando, agregar algo en el controlador para pasar este valor

Comment: Cuando construyes `$data` para despues actualizar el usuario en ningun momento le indicas el `role_user` por ese motivo es null. Fijate: `$data = $request->only('id','name','apellido','username','id_perfil','pregunta','respuesta','password');` ¿De donde sale el `role_user`?

Comment: Role_user es una tabla pivote que relaciona user y role. Sus columnas son id, role_id y user_id

Comment: que campos tiene la tabla role_user? y adicionamente agrega el error completo, ya que no esta todo el sql que esta intentando hacer en la parte que pegaste

Comment: Definite la relación en los modelos? Como?

Comment: La relacion de user y role es de muchos a muchos.

Comment: @Kinafune Revisando el codigo es posible que la ruta este mal definida y que en lugar de obtener el usuario se este creando uno nuevo por la inyeccion de dependencias por lo que el id_user es null. Una solucion seria sacar la inyeccion, y buscar el usuario manualmente `public function editar_user(Request $request, $idUser){ $user = User::findOrFail($idUser)...` o dejarnos por aqui como tienes definidas la ruta para revisarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Si intentas cambiando esta linea

```
"$user->roles()->sync($request->get('roles'))"
```

por 
`$user->roles()->attach($request->get('roles'))` asi como se muesta en la documentacion de laravel

```
"$user->roles()->attach($roleId);".
```

Espero te sirva

[Fuente](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Lo intente también con attach pero me arrojo el mismo error.